# how to take screenshot when using chrome.app.window.create

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I've created a chrome app and opening a new window in background.js using:

```
chrome.app.window.create
```

I would like to take a screenshot of the screen, but from what I've read I need to use:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab
```

but chrome.tabs is undefined

I have permissions:

```
"tabs",
"activeTab"
```

How do I take a screenshot?

Comment: [No such API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) for chrome apps. You'll need to make an additional extension.

Answer (score -1):

check the **permissions** in your **Manifest.json** file, it should conatins

In chrome **extension**:  use **chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab**.For more : [captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)
*tabs* and *activeTab*

```
"permissions": [  
    "activeTab",  
    "tabs",  
 ],
```

and in chrome **apps**::  use **chrome.desktopCapture**. for more: [chrome.desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture)

```
"permissions": [  
        "desktopCapture",   
     ],
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I forget to mention that I already have those permissions set

Comment: Bad suggestion. These permissions aren't applicable to chrome apps.

Comment: yes, you may right **wOxxOm** , that's why I updated my code.

Comment: **Andrew** , I think you should try chrome.desktopCapture